# Why my page doesn't load?

Tags: jquery, html, web

I have a webpage on http://appkon.com/demo/project2/photo.html

When I click the list item, it jump to the other page, but the page doesn't load unless I manually refresh it, I don't know why

Any help?

Comment: Your website works fine for me (Windows XP, FF 14.0.1). The longest loading time occurs for this page: http://appkon.com/demo/project2/maps.htm lIt seems, that some "heavy" plugin is used here. And you may have slow internet connection or some issues with this plugin.

Comment: I'm presuming you are talking about the first button to go to the gallery? (all of the other links appeared to work fine for me)

You have display: none; set on the div.jcbx-glry-classic, I'm not sure what exactly is causing it as I only glanced at your code, but I expect it's being caused by something in your javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember rel="external" or  data-ajax="false"

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/pages/docs-pages.html

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li><a rel="external" href="gallery/">夏日美背大作戰</a></li>
    </ul>
```

In this way, the page will be load without ajax.

Answer (score 0):

http://appkon.com/demo/project2/photo.html

http://appkon.com/demo/project2/index.html

Take View Source in browser, I can see an extra 'div' tag in the bottom of the source code. May be the reason.

```
 </div>

</div> <----------- <Extra tag>.

</body>
</html>
```